# NTPD: How to use another port than 123 for communication

Tags: ntp, ntpd

As per my understanding, ntp service will always bind with port 123.

I have tried ntpport option mentioned in https://docs.ntpsec.org/latest/ntp_conf.html. But, its not working.

Is there any option available in ntp.conf to bind another port with service Or NTPD will always listen on 123 port only?

Comment: Have you checked its listening on the new port? `netstat -a` and if it is, have you remembered to allow it through the firewall on the new port?

Comment: Note you need root/admin-level access to bind to port 123